# Composing functions 'length' and 'elemIndices'

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I wrote a function `count :: Char -> String -> Int` that counts the number of occurrences of a `Char` inside a `String`. Code sample:

```
module Main where

import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = do
        print $ count 'a' "abcaaba"

count :: Char -> String -> Int
count = length . elemIndices
```

The compile error I get is

```
* Couldn't match type `Int' with `String -> Int'
  Expected type: Char -> String -> Int
    Actual type: Char -> Int
* Possible cause: `(.)' is applied to too many arguments
  In the expression: length . elemIndices
  In an equation for `count': count = length . elemIndices
```

OK, I could write `count x y = length $ elemIndices x y` which works. But I argue we have

(1) `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

(2) `elemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]` and

(3) `length :: [a] -> Int`

If `count` shall be a composition of (2) and (3) then in (1) we need obviously `a = Char -> [Char]` and `c = Int`. And if `b = [Int]` we get

(1') `(.) :: ([Int] -> Int) -> (Char -> [Char] -> [Int]) -> Char -> [Char] -> Int`

which means I *can* compose (2) and (3) to get `Char -> [Char] -> Int`.

Questions:

1. Why is the composition I wrote failing to compile?
2. Where is my reasoning going wrong?

Comment: In many Haskell books and tutorials some of the basics of Haskell mentioned in between the lines sometimes get skipped or overlooked. [This](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2012/09/ten-things-you-should-know-about-haskell-syntax) article is a great one to have a look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`->` in types is right associative:

```
elemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
```

means

```
elemIndices :: Eq a => a -> ([a] -> [Int])
```

When you use `elemIndices` on the right-hand side of `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a' -> b) -> a' -> c`, you have

- `a' = a`
- `b = [a] -> [Int]`

And this is where things break down, because `length` does not take `[a] -> [Int]` (a function) as input; it wants a list.

---

What you can do instead is:

```
count x y = length (elemIndices x y)
```

This is the same as (by the definition of `(.)`):

```
count x y = (length . elemIndices x) y
```

Eta reduction:

```
count x = length . elemIndices x
```

You should probably stop here because this is where things get a bit crazy.

---

Prefix notation:

```
count x = (.) length (elemIndices x)
```

Definition of `(.)`:

```
count x = ((.) length . elemIndices) x
```

Eta reduction:

```
count = (.) length . elemIndices
```

Or using an operator section:

```
count = (length .) . elemIndices
```

---

But wait, there's more!

Prefix notation:

```
count = (.) ((.) length) elemIndices
```

Definition of `(.)`:

```
count = (((.) . (.)) length) elemIndices
```

Removing redundant parens:

```
count = ((.) . (.)) length elemIndices
```

Prefix notation:

```
count = (.) (.) (.) length elemIndices
```

MAXIMUM BEAUTY ACHIEVED.

Comment: Thank you for this *extraordinary* answer. Not only is it comprehensive and informative but also funny! :-)